# Is " i += arr[i++] " undefined behavior or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior

Is the below code undefined behavior in c++11 ? My feeling it's not

`i += arr[i++]`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183735/962089) has an explicit statement for `i = arr[i++]` being UB in C++11. += on top of that won't help.

Comment: It stops being UB in C++17.

Comment: _Is the below code undefined behavior in c++11?_  Yes, it is undefined behavior in C++11.  _My feeling it's not_ Your feeling has lead you astray.

Comment: Why does it matter? <g> If you have to ask, the code is badly written.

Comment: `i += arr[i]; ++i;` has a well-defined meaning and is readable.

Comment: Didnt know it was ub before, what is this?!